# How do I show bindings in in an IHaskell Notebook?

Tags: haskell, ghci, jupyter, ihaskell

In GHCi I can show current bindings by executing

```
:show bindings
```

but when I try this in an IHaskell Notebook I get

> Parse error (line 1, column 1): Unknown directive: 'show'.

Is there a way to get a list of (and perhaps even remove specific) bindings in an IHaskell Notebook? If not, why can I do this in GHCi but not in a Notebook (I suspect the answer reveals something generally important about the architecture of Haskell IO and how that's employed by IHaskell)?

Comment: I guess you get an answer here at some point - but in this case isn't this more like an *issue* you could bring up on https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell ?

Comment: @Carsten: I'll do that too. But I suspect it is due to something architectural that will reveal a bit about how IHaskell, IO, and GHC(i) are related.

Comment: Well, the relationship between IHaskell and GHC**i** is pretty simple: **absolutely none**. IHaskell uses the GHC *libraries* to *reimplement* the whole interactive interpreter. So you shouldn't associate GHCi behaviours/commands with IHaskell. AFAIK currently there is no way to display what you want, but I don't think it's due to any limitation of the system but simply because IHaskell doesn't implement all the directives that GHCi has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [not supported](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell/issues/559) in IHaskell (0.6.5.0; yet) but may be in the future.